Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-p5' in '/home/runner/work/A.I./A.I./src' when deploying git-pages
Link to Repository
Image of failed deploy
I created a custom workflow for my gh-pages, but this package always fails at Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-p5' in '/home/runner/work/A.I./A.I./src'.
I have made sure react-p5 is installed and made sure I have imported them correctly.

i don't see the package being added into package.json, nor package-lock.json. you should add it into your package.json and run the install script again?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
